# Hide a particular header and it's corresponding column in vuetify datatable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

it's listed here that we can attach some class to it and it will be taken care of .i'm still confused on how to use  this.

```
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/1863
```

The codepen

```
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBMZgB
```

suppose i want to hide the calories column. then how should i do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The headers object can be a computed property, so you don't need CSS to hide it. Have your computedHeaders function filter your headers array.

```js
computed: {
   computedHeaders () {
      return this.headers.filter(....Your filter logic here)  
   }
}
```

Change your headers bind in your html to point to 'computedHeaders' instead of headers

```js
:headers="computedHeaders"
```

Comment: I need to use the value of that column in further when editing the cell item. i'm not sure how to do with computed property. do i still get my hidden value afterwards for calculation. A codepen will sure help. thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll still have access to the hidden value, with the computed property, the original 'headers' array doesn't get modified, so you'd use that one for your calculations.

Comment: Added quick codepen  - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeWRvN There are cleaner ways to code it, and you might not want to toggle it with a button, but you get the idea!

Answer (score 59):

In case you still need the column to be filterable (with a search input for instance) you can simply add `d-none` (with a leading space) to the `align` property of the header.

```
headers: [
    {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name',
    },
    { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: ' d-none' }, // ' d-none' hides the column but keeps the search ability
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
  ]
```

Example, if I want to hide the category column but be able to search through it.

https://codepen.io/simondepelchin/pen/JjjEmGm

Edit: Note that this will still show the header when the table switched to mobile rows.

Comment: align: ' d-none'.   
Thank you very much !!!!
Bootstrap 4 Best way and smart way!!!

Comment: Any hints on how to hide this on mobile?

Comment: @alfreema Take a look at [Vuetify's display helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#display). Maybe try `d-none d-md-table-cell`

Comment: don't remove the leading space from ' d-none'

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on [SimonDepelchin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502035):

The `align` property in the header specification of a given column, e.g.

`{ text: 'some text', value: 'category', align: 'XXX' },`

is converted into a `class` property of the given `<td>` element like this

`<td class="text-XXX">{{item.category}}</td>`

If `XXX` begins with a space, you can use this to give the td cell any class you like:

`{ text: 'some text', value: 'category', align: ' d-none' },`

becomes

`<td class="text- d-none">{{item.category}}</td>`

`d-none` is defined in [vuetify.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.5/dist/vuetify.min.css) as `.d-none{display:none!important}.v-application`. However, you do not need to load [vuetify.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.5/dist/vuetify.min.css) for this trick to work: just put `.d-none{display:none!important}` anywhere in your css definition.

Note, however, that when the table responsively changes to mobile view, the value of `align` is ignored, and thus the corresponding element is not hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [SimonDepelchin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502035):

You can just set the header class and cell class to 'hidden', the effect is going to be the same, just without it looking like hack

```
headers: [
{
  text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
  align: 'left',
  sortable: false,
  value: 'name',
},
{ text: 'Category', value: 'category', class: "hidden", cellClass: "hidden" }...
```

Comment: this solution is also compatible with the `DataTableHeader` TypeScript interface. Assuming you have a css `hidden` class defined. you can also use the `d-none` class instead

Comment: within the `hidden` css class defined, you can just put `display: none;` css property and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on contributions on how to make a property of a v-data-table item **filterable and not displayed** in the table:

Instead of hiding the column you can simply exclude it from the data-table `headers` field and make use of the `item` argument of the filter function.

Example (based on provided one):

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="calories"
        type="number"        
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      calories: '',
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0
        },
        ...
      ],
      // Calories column removed from headers:
      headers: [
        { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    customFilter (value, search, item) {
      // Custom filter logic
      // Example: keep only items having calories up to the provided input
      const { calories } = this
      if (calories && Number(calories) && Number.isInteger(calories)) {
        return item.calories <= calories
      }
      
      return true
    }
  }
}
```