# VueJS: How to hide some data table columns on mobile size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to hide some data table columns on mobile size, here is the table's code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Nutrition
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="search"
          label="Search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :search="search"
      ></v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

or you can find the full code here: https://codepen.io/simondepelchin/pen/JjjEmGm

The columns will be wrapped down on mobile size, and I want to hide some columns.
how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display) is super clear on that, please read through it.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625562/hide-a-particular-header-and-its-corresponding-column-in-vuetify-datatable/58502035#58502035) will help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the responsive display classes in the headers `align` option of the desired column(s). For example, here Category and Calories are only shown on `lg` and wider...

```
 headers: [
    {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name',
    },
    { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: ' d-none d-lg-table-cell' }, 
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', align: ' d-none d-lg-table-cell' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
  ],
```

Note: The leading space is important since the align option is appended to other classes when each column/cell is rendered. Also notice using `d-lg-table-cell` instead of `d-block` for the correct table display.

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/hMh9qLMi3T

Comment: the colums are hidden on sm size and above, but still wrapped down on xs. Is there any another way to solve this?

Comment: I just used lg for the example.. use sm, md, etc... or whatever you want

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, using `' d-none d-sm-table-cell'` or `' d-none d-xs-table-cell'` still causes the column to render on mobile.

Comment: There is no `d-xs-table-cell`

Answer (score -1):

add `align: ' d-none d-md-block'` in your headers data.
like this:

```
{ text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' , align: ' d-none d-md-block'}
```